# Set global variables dynamically

Tags: tibco

I'm still a newbie with BW. I try to set JMS queue destination name dynamically from an input which I receive from a webservice.

Problem with this is that BW only allows me to set the queue name statically or referencing a global variable. Is there any way to set a global variable dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

click on the JMS sender activity. Select the "Input" tab. Open the "ActivityInput" node. The child node 'destinationQueue' is what you are looking for.

[image]

HTH,

Hendrik